# Java JNA - detect when registry value changes

Tags: java, windows, registry, jna

My application needs to be alerted when a specific registry value changes.  [This RegNotifyChangeKeyValue  function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regnotifychangekeyvalue) appears to do what I need, however it's not ported over to JNA from what I can tell.  The only registry functionality I can find with JNA is [Advapi32Util](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32Util.html), which would give me the ability to continually read values, but I really do not want to do that.

Anyone know how I can use RegNotifyChangeKeyValue within a Java app?

Comment: JNA doesn't support specific APIs, it should be able to handle any method call through i dont know how it supports call backs.

Comment: "Not ported over to JNA" ... yet.   The project is user-supported!  You can always write your own `Advapi32` class extending the JNA version and adding the function.   And once you get it working you can contribute it to JNA!